# How can scrapy get the second <a href> inside of div class?

Tags: python, html, scrapy, css-selectors, parsel

I just trying to get `url` from in a `div class`. But this `div` has two `<a href>`. So, that can get the first one but that should get second one. How can I do this?

This is the html code of website:

```
 <div class="active"> 
          <a href="javascript:;" class=" add-favorite  j-lightbox-popup-button " data-target="howGoingCheckoutNotRedirect"> <i data-feather="heart"></i> </a> 
          <a href="/urun/yohegoalhareketli-kale-112432">
```

This is my Python code:

```
product_link = container.a["href"]
```

It gets `javascript:;` inside of `a["href"]`

All my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import os
from joker import joker
import requests


product_joker_array = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Shop Name','Product Name','Product Price','Product Image Url','Product Url']) 


for categories in range(0,len(joker.joker_category_names)):
    url = joker.joker_url  + joker.joker_category_names[categories]
    print(url)


    for pages in range(0,250):
        url = (joker.joker_url  + joker.joker_category_names[categories] + "#/page={}".format(pages))
        print(url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.text

        page_soup = soup(data, 'lxml')

        #time.sleep(10)
        containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class": "active"})
        #print(containers)
        len(containers)
        try:
            container = containers[0]
        except IndexError:
            print("Index Error")
            break

        #print(container)

        for container in containers:

            product_image = container.findAll("div", {"class": "image-link"})
            product_final_image = product_image[0].img["src"].strip()
            print("Product Image Url : " + product_final_image )

            product_desc = container.findAll("div", {"class": "image-link"})
            #print("asdasdas", product_desc)
            product_final_desc = product_desc[0].img["alt"].strip()
            print("product_final_desc : ",product_final_desc)

            #product_link = container.a["href"]
            product_link = container.xpath('.//a[2]/@href').extract_first()
            print("link : ",product_link)

            product_final_link = joker.joker_url + product_link
            print("final link : ",product_final_link)     



            product_price = container.findAll("span",{"class": "discount-price"})

            product_final_price = product_price[0].text.replace(" ", "")
            product_final_price = product_final_price.strip()
            print("product_final : ",product_final_price)
            #if "," not in product_final_price:
                                         #product_final_price = product_final_price + ",00"
                                         #print("product ,00",product_final_price)
            product_market_name = 'Joker'

            #print("Product Price:" + product_final_price )
            product_joker_array.loc[len(product_joker_array)] = [product_market_name,product_final_desc,product_final_price,product_final_image,product_final_link]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with these codes:

```
product_link = container.find("div", {"class": "active"})
            product_link = product_link.findAll("a")
            product_final_link = joker.joker_url + product_link[1]["href"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a scrapy selector method to get the url, use the following syntax:

```
response.css('base::attr(href)').getall()
```

Comment: It sho this error: **AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'css'**

Comment: hmm.. I suggested removing the css tag from this question because I thought it wouldn't be relevant to the question or answer.. and then I see you relating a css selector based solution... can you correct my bad presumption if this is a possible solution.

Comment: @AhmetYılmaz the documentation for scrapy does reference to the existence of `.css()` extension method that uses css selectors. (as well as xpath). see [selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Comment: seems there is a dependency on [parcel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), so that could be the issue you saw. potentially worth adding to this answer.  may want to tag the question with `parcel` and `css-selector` as well.

Comment: @BrettCaswell ok. I added these two tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version (get `href` for the second `a` from your `container` element):

```
container.xpath('.//a[2]/@href').extract_first()
```

**UPDATE** Looks like you have a `None` for `container`. Try this:
    response.xpath('.//a[2]/@href').extract_first()

Comment: I tried. It happen this error: **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**

Comment: **'Response' object has no attribute 'xpath'** That's problem now. I think `container` should be truth. Because I can get first `a href` successfully with this way.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Scrapy? How did you get `container`?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure. I just write phyton code but most of code wrote from my work mate. It say `import as beautiful soap`.  I can write all code of it here. It's not much.

Comment: I believe you're not using Scrapy at all :-(